# sessionStorage.clear() not working

Tags: javascript, php, session, storage, session-storage

I'm using sessionStorage successfully in a project, with one caveat: I can't eliminate the storage with the `clear()` operator, as documented.

I'm doing this when logging out of the administrative mode of my site, which involves clicking on a Log Out item in a list, like this:

```
<li><a href="admin_logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
```

The `admin_logout.php` file then destroys session variables, etc., and then redirects to the home page of the site. Its previous form, which works, is:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
@header('Location:./');
exit;
?>
```

That all works fine. What I can't seem to integrate into the routine is clearing the sessionStorage. For the text of my `admin_logout.php` file, I've tried:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<script>
sessionStorage.clear();
</script>

<?php
session_destroy();
@header('Location:./');
exit;
?>
```

...as well as:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo '<script>';
echo 'sessionStorage.clear();';
echo '</script>';

session_destroy();
@header('Location:./');
exit;
?>
```

Perhaps pointing to the root cause is that when I've placed:

```
?>
<script>
alert("HELLO");
</script>
<?php
```

...within this script, the alert is never executed, yet everything else is. How can I invoke the `<script>` based `sessionStorage.clear()` operation to clear my session storage items within the routine listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're redirecting on the server-side and the `sessionStorage.clear()` is happening on the client side.  I believe you're redirecting before that gets a chance to run.

Comment: Why, then, would the alert() not run when placed in the same location in the file? It should run regardless. That's why I'm suspicious.

Comment: the alert is also client-side code.  Javascript in general gets no chance to run because you redirect before it's ever rendered in a browser.

Comment: You were right...I've had to device a callback to make it work. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Allicam was correct; I needed to encapsulate the storage clearing code in a callback function:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
<script type="text/javascript">

function firstFunction(_callback){
    sessionStorage.clear();
    _callback();
}

function secondFunction(){
    firstFunction(function() {
        window.location = './';
    });    
}
secondFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: Had the exact same problem, except my alert was being called. Tks